# Restrict asmx access to local

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

Is there a way to restrict asmx to be accessed local only? I have an webservice just for jquery, I don't want to expose it.

Comment: jquery runs client-side - so what do you mean by local access?

Comment: Do you mean to be accessed only by jquery and not from the navigation bar or anything else?

Comment: @jfmags you're correct, i miss this info.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure allowed ip addresses on IIS.

[For IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/8ad5602b-1f0d-4dc6-a288-c571394dc095.mspx?mfr=true), [For IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731598%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Or you can check IP address of client and its not local ip can throw exception or do whatever you like.

Comment: This can be of some difficulty in an shared hosting environment.